# Empty file created while fetching Blob file from oracle 11g xe

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Below given are two programs for

1> storing blob file into database

and

2> retrieving blob file from database

**1. storing blob file into database**

```
package jdbc;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;



public class Storing_Image {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user", "system");
    p.put("password", "password");

    URL url = Storing_Clob.class.getResource("/images/bunny.jpg");
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",p);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into myblob(BLOB_FILE) values(?)");

 pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (byte)file.length());

    System.out.println("Length of string: "+file.length());
    System.out.println("No of rows affected: "+pstmt.executeUpdate());
    con.close();
}
}
```

The myblob table has only one coloumn of Blob datatype.

After inserting into  the table I executed the following command:-

```
select * from myblob;
```

which gave the following output:-

[image: myblob.jpg]![result of myblob table contents]

which i guess is the byte value of the picture in the table.

**2.Retrieving Blob File(image) from database**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.*;

public class Retrieving_Image {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user", "system");
    p.put("password", "password");

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",p);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select BLOB_FILE from myblob",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    rs.first();

        InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("H:/result1.jpg");


    while(((byte) is.read())!=-1)
    {
        fos.write((byte) is.read());
    }

    fos.close();
    con.close();
 }
}
```

which gives the following output:-

[image: image fetched from database]

which as you can see is a blank image i.e. 0kb.
I am using oracle 11g xe and ojdbc6_g.jar driver.

Comment: Have you tried **fos.flush();** before close?

Comment: @ThrashBean yes.It doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you debug a bit and check if while loop is executed or `is.read()` stops at first read?
Also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445960/java-reading-blob-from-oracle?rq=1

Comment: @bellabax well i did the following : `int counter = 0;while(( is.read())!=-1)
  {
   System.out.println("counter is: "+(++counter));
   fos.write((byte) is.read());
  }` it gives me the following output:- `counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 10
` can u pls telly it with the sql cmd output image that i have provided. thnks.