# Error in casting of objects in oracle multimedia

Tags: java, database, oracle, multimedia

I have written some code that retrieves a video from a database. This video is stored as a BLOB file. I have retrieved it in

```
    package edu.jay.fyp.featureextractor.database;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet;
import oracle.ord.im.OrdVideo;

public class OracleConnector {

    private static final String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@jay_tank-pc:1521:fyp";
    private static final String user = "SYSTEM";
    private static final String pwd = "xyz";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,user,pwd);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            String query = "select video_name, video_content from system.videos where sr_no = '1'";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            OracleResultSet rs = (OracleResultSet) ps.executeQuery();
            OrdVideo videoProxy = null;
            if(rs.next()){

                 rs.getORAData("video_content", OrdVideo.getORADataFactory());
            }
            //System.out.println(videoProxy.getBitRate());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I used code similar to the code given in Oracle's documentation, but when I run my code, I get the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BLOB cannot be cast to oracle.sql.STRUCT
    at oracle.ord.im.OrdVideo.create(OrdVideo.java:1797)
    at oracle.ord.im.OrdVideo$1.create(OrdVideo.java:1786)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.getORAData(Accessor.java:1387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getORAData(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1408)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getORAData(OracleResultSet.java:632)
    at edu.jay.fyp.featureextractor.database.OracleConnector.main(OracleConnector.java:28)
```

Comment: The error is on line 28 of your file, can you point to which line that is?

Comment: rs.getORAData("video_content", OrdVideo.getORADataFactory());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know much about this but I've done some research.

The error, if you read it says that a blob cannot be cast to a struct. That gives you a hint that you're providing wrong arguments to the getORAData().

I went and looked at the definition, and it says:

`Get the column value as an instance of a subclass of ORAData`

Well, if you look at the ORAData definition it doesn't seem to support BLOB, but only more common value types.

So, clearly that is not the way to retrieve a BLOB from the DB.

Searching on how to actually do that, I found this [Java: Reading Blob from Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445960/java-reading-blob-from-oracle)

In the response you can see that he suggest using `ResultSet.getBinaryStream()`

So your code should probably be:

```
rs.getBinaryStream("video_content")
```

Or

```
rs.getBytes("video_content")
```

Of course now you have to pick up the InputStream or the byte[] results and do something with them, but I'll leave that for you.

Comment: I am able to get BLOB from DB using rs.getBLOB("video_content"). I want to get information about video using various methods that are defined in ORDVideo.

Comment: That seems to be a different question from what you asked here. The exception seems to be taken care of, so you should mark this one as resolved by accepting my answer or posting your own solution and then open a new question with that.