# How to convert binary data back into a valid file?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a Java script, that will get the BLOB data from the database and then email this file to a specific email address. My problem is, that I have to use some framework functions (I can make DB calls only through these) and I think it's not handling BLOB datatypes... All I can get is the string representation of the result, this is the log line result of the code (framework call):

```
String s = String.valueOf(result.get(j).getValue("BLOB_DATA"));
System.out.println(s);
```

Log result:

```
<binary data> 50 KB
```

So this is the data I have to convert SOMEHOW into a valid pdf file, but right now I'm stuck...

Is it even possible to convert it into a valid `byte[]`? I tried it several ways, but all I get is invalid files... :(

Comment: What is `result`? Is it a `List`? What types does it store?

Comment: You got me confused by writing "java script" (sound much like javascript). Mind talking about Java program ?

Comment: Try new String(result.get(j).getValue("BLOB_DATA")); It works in case if byte data.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445960/java-reading-blob-from-oracle

Comment: is result.get(j).getValue("BLOB_DATA") return the data type java.sql.Blob?

If yes, please refer to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662432/easiest-way-to-convert-a-blob-into-a-byte-array

If no, then what is the data type returned by result.get(j).getValue("BLOB_DATA")?

Comment: Welll... If I try to CAST the result: Blob s = (Blob)result.get(j).findValue("PDF"); to Java Blob it says "java.lang.ClassCastException: ifs.fnd.ap.Bytedata cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob"

Comment: ifs.fnd.ap.Bytedata bytedata = (ifs.fnd.ap.Bytedata) result.get(j).findValue("PDF");
 then look up the java doc for ifs.fnd.ap.Bytedata to see how to convert this datatype to byte array.

Comment: "All I can get is the string representation" which is not the binary data.